# '?' Operator has icompatible types

Tags: rust, blockchain

I'm writing a contract for secret network in the cosmwasm ecosystem using rust. Below mentioned is a function that is giving an error. Its a callback message that is called whenever a contract receives an nft

```
#[allow(clippy::too_many_arguments)]
fn receiver_callback_msgs<S: Storage, A: Api, Q: Querier>(
    deps: &mut Extern<S, A, Q>,
    env: &Env,
    contract_human: &HumanAddr,
    contract: &CanonicalAddr,
    receiver_info: Option<ReceiverInfo>,
    send_from_list: Vec<SendFrom>,
    msg: &Option<Binary>,
    sender: &HumanAddr,
    receivers: &mut Vec<CacheReceiverInfo>,
) -> StdResult<Vec<CosmosMsg>> {
    let (code_hash, impl_batch) = if let Some(supplied) = receiver_info {
        (
            supplied.recipient_code_hash,
            supplied.also_implements_batch_receive_nft.unwrap_or(false),
        )
    } else if let Some(receiver) = receivers.iter().find(|&r| r.contract == *contract) {
        (
            receiver.registration.code_hash.clone(),
            receiver.registration.impl_batch,
        )
    } else {
        let store = ReadonlyPrefixedStorage::new(PREFIX_RECEIVERS, &deps.storage);
        let registration: ReceiveRegistration =
            may_load(&store, contract.as_slice())?.unwrap_or(ReceiveRegistration {
                code_hash: String::new(),
                impl_batch: false,
            });
        let receiver = CacheReceiverInfo {
            contract: contract.clone(),
            registration: registration.clone(),
        };
        receivers.push(receiver);
        (registration.code_hash, registration.impl_batch)
    };
    if code_hash.is_empty() {
        return Ok(Vec::new());
    }
    let mut callbacks: Vec<CosmosMsg> = Vec::new();
    for send_from in send_from_list.into_iter() {
        // if BatchReceiveNft is implemented, use it
        if impl_batch {
            callbacks.push(try_receive(
                &mut deps,
                sender.clone(),
                send_from.owner,
                &send_from.token_ids,
                msg.clone(),
                code_hash.clone(),
               // contract_human.clone(),
            )?);
        }
        }
        Ok(callbacks)
    }
```

which returns the error:

[image]

I am new to rust so need some help in resolving this

this is try_receive signature

```
pub fn try_receive<S: Storage, A: Api, Q: Querier>(
    deps: &mut Extern<S, A, Q>,
    sender: HumanAddr,
    from: HumanAddr,
    token_ids: &[String],
    msg: Option<Binary>,
    code_hash: String,

) -> HandleResult
```

Comment: Your error text looks like it got garbled, could you fix it up? Hard to understand in its current state.

Comment: What does `try_receive`'s signature look like?

Comment: @Anemoia added the signature above

Comment: [Please do not upload text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please try to write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your problem. It's hard to give you advice without knowing what `HandleResult` (or `HandleResponse`, your question is inconsistent), `CosmosMsg` and `StdResult` are.

Comment: I think your question is wrong. The `?` operator does not give you an error. It unwraps `HandleResult` to `HandleResponse`, and the `push()` gives you the error.

Comment: @Finomnis Isn't that strange `?` only tries to convert the `Error` variant of `Result`? And it is a conversion error.  I wonder how `StdResult` is defined.

Comment: @ÖmerErden im not sure what you mean; that's exactly how the `?` operator is defined. If the value is an `Err`, it returns it from the current function, calling `into` in the process. If it's `Ok`, it simply unwraps it. That's not strange, that's expected.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Ah wait you are right, it *is* a conversion error. OK now I'm super confused how `?` works internally. I agree, more context is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `receiver_callback_msgs` expects a return type of `StdResult<Vec<CosmosMsg>>` but when you are using `try_receive(...)?` you are returning a type of `Ok(Vec<HandleResponse>)` which isn't the same as parent function's return.

So you can manually convert from `HandleResponse` to `CosmosMsg` as rust expects, or you can implement an [Into Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html) which is a better approach.

Comment: If that's what he actually needs, I feel like his code might be incorrect. `CosmosMsg` does not sound like an error type to me.

Comment: It's the `Ok` variant of the `StdResult` that is being used. Moreover, its returning  `Ok(Vec<HandleResult>)` whereas expected is `Ok(Vec<CosmosMsg>)`

Comment: Aaah the error doesn't come from the `?` but from the `push()`?

Comment: Yes I think the `Err` variant matches the return type but not the `Ok` Variant

Comment: Maybe `HandleResult` unwraps to `HandleResponse`? That would make much more sense